# Experiencing an error "Cannot complete the request" trying to Install New Software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I click on Help/Install New Software and I get this error:
[image]

**Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200**

Here is the error log:

```
!SESSION 2018-08-27 07:07:58.698 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.3.M20180330-0640
java.version=1.8.0_181
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2018-08-27 07:08:01.360
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Eclipse Oxygen\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getSharedPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    ... 12 more
Root exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Registry Directory not available: c:\Program Files\Eclipse Oxygen\p2\org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine\profileRegistry.
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(LazyProfileRegistry.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.LazyProfileRegistry.containsProfile(LazyProfileRegistry.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.containsProfile(ProfilePreferences.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.ProfilePreferences.load(ProfilePreferences.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.getNode(RootPreferences.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.RootPreferences.node(RootPreferences.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.getSharedPreferences(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.restoreRepositories(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:1016)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.basicGetRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:649)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:933)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1614)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2018-08-27 07:08:25.897
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\nicholdw'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2018-08-27 07:09:30.159
!MESSAGE Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file.
```

---

Comment: How was this originally installed? Where is it installed?

Comment: How? I don't understand . I assume it was downloaded from eclipse.org. It's installed locally on the PC.

Comment: Ok, but installed *how*? You're glossing over the details that matter the most.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you want to know. What details do you want?

Comment: What did you download? What did you do with it to get to the point where you could run it and then choose Help->Install New Software? All of it. You apparently put this under the "Program Files" directory--do you have unconditional write access there? Do you have *read* access to all of it?

Answer (score -1):

Check your update urls . may be one or more of your update url are pointing to a wrong link.

Comment: It's more a comment. If you just suggesting idea of double-checking without hard-evidence that it's reason of problem - please use comment.